# How to instantly suspend user and not after user log out

Tags: php, mysql

I have one script that works via mysql and php.
Now I have a problem, namely if the user does not pay the monthly subscription, it is necessary after 10 days from the day of the invoice creation  to suspend the user's account but the problem is:

the user account is suspended only after the user is log out of the client area, I need the user account to be suspended immediately while it is still logged.

I need this because if the user's account is not suspended while logged in then he can use the services for free as long as he is logged in.

These are parts of the code from the two scripts for the user suspend account, if it is possible to add some part of the code so that the user is suspended immediately after 10 days not paying the invoice and not only after log out.

```
     <?php 
       $todayDate = Date('Y-m-d');
       $extendExpiredDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($user->expire_date ." +10 days"));
       if ($todayDate < $extendExpiredDate && $user->is_active != 2) { 
     ?>
       <li><a href="<?php HREF('/upload-file.php'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i> <span>Upload</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php HREF('/list.php'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow"></i> <span>List Uploaded </span></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php HREF('/translate.php'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-blue"></i> <span>Translate </span></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php HREF('/converter.php'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-green"></i> <span>Convert </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php HREF('/display.php'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-green"></i> <span>search</span></a></li>
     <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
```

```
function db_getUserActiveStatus($id)
   {
       $userdb = new ezSQL_mysqli(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
   
       $usersql = "SELECT is_active FROM tbl_users WHERE id = %s;";
       $userquery = $userdb->prepare($usersql,$id);
       $userStatus = $userdb->get_row($userquery);
   
       $suspendUser = $userStatus->is_active != 2 ? 2 : 1;
   
       return $suspendUser;
   
   }
   
   function db_suspendUser($id)
   {
       $status = db_getUserActiveStatus($id);
   
       $db = new ezSQL_mysqli(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
       $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET is_active=%d WHERE id=%s";
   
       $query = $db->prepare($sql, $status, $id);
   
       $db->query($query);
       return $db->rows_affected;
   }
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to force the end user to log off upon suspension?

Comment: As far as I know, unless you've got some kind of async infrastructure (like web sockets), you can't really force the end user to log off to be suspended.

You can get around this by continuously polling for a suspension response via sql trigger, but that's A LOT of overhead and not feasible.

Comment: A possibility is setting the subscription end timestamp in session and on each page load checking to see if the current time is less than the subscription end timestamp. If not, then log the user out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make every page load verify the logged in user. When the user is suspended, the next time he or she attempts to load a page, he or she will be locked out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Paul, can you please share piece of code that I can use for the answer above, I would appreciate that a lot?

Comment: I would use your own code that you show at the top of your question. But I would place an if like if ($todayDate > $extendExpiredDate) { // go do something that makes them pay }. I would add that to the top of every PHP file on your website. Then nothing loads without that check.